# Using Separate Stylesheet for Multishipping Checkout in Magento 1.6

Tags: magento, checkout

Currently I am setting up a Multishipping checkout on one of my sites running Magento 1.6. I have been using the default Multishipping checkout for Magento, however I cannot style the new checkout appropriately because the classes for the new checkout are named the same as the ones I use for the One Page checkout I also have.

Does anyone know how to attach a completely separate stylesheet for the Multishipping checkout. I have tried using the `Page.xml` file and adding in a new action class for it, however, I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your local.xml layout file:

```
<checkout_multishipping>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
           <css>your/cssfile.css</css>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_multishipping>
```

**edit** - removed translate attribute

The **checkout_multishipping** layout update handle is added via layout update directives for each `checkout_multishipping` action.

Note that it is also possible to target CSS rules using the fullactionname CSS classnames added to the body tag:

[image: screenshot of body tag in page source]

Comment: Thank You for your reply benmarks. As I am fairly new to magento I am still trying to understand were all the files are located. Could you point me in the direction of the local.xml file if possible please. I have been looking in the app/layout folder were the majority of the .xml files are stored however I am unable to identify a local.xml file. Sorry if this is a silly question. I was able to find a local.xml in app/etc however I think this folder may be a back up of a previous folder. As you can probably tell it was not me who installed Magento and set it up. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a silly question, as local.xml doesn't exist in layouts. It's meant only for you, so create it in your theme's layout folder and have at it :-)

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now. So I just create a local.xml file in the layout folder? Would it be possible just to add the code into the checkout.xml it seems to have Multishipping sections where the code could be placed. Thanks again :)!

Comment: All layout xml from all files is merged together, so it *generally* doesn't matter where the directive is. It's a preferred practice to not customize core layout files, but if you already are, then go for it!

Comment: I tryed adding it into the checkout.xml and it didn't change the layout to the new stylesheet. I also added a local.xml file and wrote up the code this didn't work either. Im Probably making rookie mistakes but as I said I am fairly new to Magento and so far finding it hard to grasp the file sturcture. Thanks for the reply my collegue is actually on holiday atm and he asked me to try and research this a little to help him derieve a solution for when he is back. Multishiping is a MUST for the company. The functionality is brilliant, styling is terrible. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't forget about the layout xml cache which can be administered in System > Cache Management

Comment: I have flushed the cache after the new files have been added it does not make a difference at the minute.

Comment: Note: removed translate attribute. Not needed, possibly problematic